# C# Saving data from label and loading it from textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, save, label

I made an app for investment bank. My problem is that I need to save the transaction information as transaction number, so later if I write the transaction number into a textbox, the form with this only data  will appear as a labels

I would really appreciate if you could help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can display the same form, just set Enabled property of your textbox to false to prevent further editing